# JSON calls not working after switching type to POST instead of GET

Tags: jquery, json, jayrock

I have been using the JayRock framework with ASP.NET to return JSON being consume via javascript.  Everything has worked fine until I changed the $.ajax call from a GET to a POST.  Upon that change I now receive this error.

```
{"id":null,"error":{"name":"JSONRPCError","message":"Missing value.","errors":[{"name":"JsonException","message":"Missing value."}]}}
```

Here is my javascript:

```
    var tmp = '{ "assID": 52 }';
    var tmpObj = $.parseJSON(tmp);


$.ajax
({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/jsonC.ashx/tester',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: tmpObj,
    async: true,
    contentType: 'application/json',
   success: function (result) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
    }
})
```

Anyone have any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is that url expecting to receive a post? If it's only look for GET values, then you'd still have to pass parameters in the URL.

Comment: Same thought as Marc, but the right thing to do is get the parameters on the server side from the POST, not to send them redundantly in the URL.

Comment: I don't guess I understand,  I'm using Jayrock,  I assume it handles the difference for me?  I can't seem to find any setting..  I have googled this problem all day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the definition of what should do:

```
var dataString = '{ "assID": 52 }'; 
var postData = $.parseJSON(dataString);
var response;
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/jsonC.ashx/tester',
  contentType: 'application/json',
  data: JSON.stringify(postData),
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
      //do something for success if you want. If your response is JSON:
      response = $.parseJSON(data)
  },
  error: function(data) {
      //do somtething for error if you want. If your response is JSON:
      response = $.parseJSON(data)
  }
});
```

Comment: actually i was attempting to send data,  but simplified the code just to try to get a response from a post..  here is the data.. 



        var tmp = '{ "assID": 52 }';
        var tmpObj = $.parseJSON(tmp);



then within the ajax call..

 data: tmpObj,

Comment: making progress...now I get a server error I can see with firebug..  "Notification are not yet supported."   Jayrock issue?

Comment: Does your problem is that: `If the ID is not there or was not set then this is a notification request from the client that does not expect any response. Right now, we don't support this.` from here: http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/CSharp/Development/Jayrock/Jayrock/JsonRpc/JsonRpcDispatcher.cs.htm

Comment: so it means you should set `id` to something. I mean as like: var dataString = '{ "id" : 1, "assID": 52 }';

Comment: Oh excellent @kamaci  So, I included the id,  it complained about not having a method call,  so i included the name of the method.. now its saying message: "Parameter count mismatch."...  any chance you would know the syntax to include that one parameter.. everything i have tried has failed..  thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your parameters as data in the config values...

```
$.ajax
({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/jsonC.ashx/tester',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {id: some_value, other_var: 'some string'}
    async: true,
    contentType: 'application/json',
   success: function (result) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
    }
})
```

just replace the contents of data with your actual values. As it stands you are posting to a page but sending no post vars.